# Can particles become entangled by every of the three basic forces, or even by gravity?

Tags: gravity, quantum-entanglement, weak-interaction, strong-force

A pair of particles can become [entangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) after having had an e.m interaction. Almost every example of entanglement is that of electrons whose spins become entangled having had an e.m. interaction, or the entanglement of photons, the carriers of the e.m. force. There is such a thing as "entanglement swapping" (see the Wikipedia article) but that's begging the question.

So is the same (becoming entangled) true for particles that have interacted by means of one of the other two basic forces or maybe even gravity, which, I suppose, is overwhelmed by the other forces, but the particles that interact gravitationally are at least indistinguishable, and the same before and after the interaction and this is not the case in most of the weak and strong force interactions (correct me if I am wrong)?

Answer (score 2):

Entanglement is not something magical. It is  a consequence of the underlying quantum mechanical framework of all nature. It really means that there exists a quantum mechanical solution which describes the system, where all participating particles have a mathematically defined role. So mathematically, in principle, the answer is yes. BUT

The strong force and the weak force are [*very short ranged,*](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) the strong because of asymptotic  freedom  and color neutrality,and the weak because of the very large mass of the W and Z. One cannot set up experiments with color entanglement, for example, the way one can do spin entanglements. One can describe the wavefunction of a system but there is no handle to manipulate it in the way one can  the long range electromagnetic interaction.

Gravity is long range, but [so very weak](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) that its effects cannot be measured between elementary particles. Only in large massive ensembles,
 where the quantum mechanical nature is statistically overwhelmed, gravity plays a role.